# How to wait for all the functions and then render in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting data from API's and here is my functions

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getSeller();
  getReviews();
}, []);

const getSeller = async () => {
  let data = await api.get(`/${itemSeller}/`).then(({ data }) => data);
  setUser({ user: data[0].first_name + ' ' + data[0].last_name });
};

const getReviews = async () => {
  let data = await ReviewsApi.get(`/${itemId}/`).then(({ data }) => data);
  data.map((a) => getReviewGiverName(a, data));
};

const getReviewGiverName = async (a, data) => {
  let data1 = await api.get(`/${a.buyer}/`).then(({ data }) => data);
  a.buyername = data1[0].first_name + ' ' + data1[0].last_name;
  setReviews(data);
};
```

I am adding a new field buyer name to my reviews list which in which I have stored data from API.
But the problem is that if I ```console.log(reviews)```` it displays correctly the buyer name in every object of reviews list but if I render these on-screen through map function.... it displays some buyer name but for some buyer name it shows empty space.

[image: screen]

Comment: Is [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) what you are looking for?

Comment: Sounds more like you are asking how to "wait to render" until your state has populated. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do it like this will help

```js
const getReviews = () => {
  ReviewsApi.get(`/${itemId}/`).then(({ data }) =>
    data.map((a) => getReviewGiverName(a, data))
  );
};
```

OR

You can focus on the `setReviews` state so it will re-render whenever reviews change.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getSeller();
  getReviews();
}, [reviews]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is that if I `console.log(reviews)` it displays
> correctly the buyer name in every object of reviews list but if I
> render these on-screen through map function.... it displays some buyer
> name but for some buyer name it shows empty space.

It seems you are enqueueing multiple asynchronous requests in a loop, and each one is independently updating state.

There also appears to be some object mutations going on when `getReviewGiverName` is appending new `buyername` property to `a` which is a review object in `data`.

You are also mixing `async/await` syntax with Promise chains. Generally you should pick one or the other.

```
const getReviews = async () => {
  let data = await ReviewsApi.get(`/${itemId}/`)
    .then(({ data }) => data);
  data.map(a => getReviewGiverName(a, data))     
}

const getReviewGiverName = async (a, data) => {
  let data1 = await api.get(`/${a.buyer}/`)
    .then(({ data} ) => data);
  a.buyername = data1[0].first_name + ' ' + data1[0].last_name;
  setReviews(data) ;
}
```

To resolve I suggest mapping the `getReviewGiverName` requests into an array of Promises and `Promise.all` them and *then* update/set the `reviews` state. In the `getReviewGiverName` fetch the review's buyer and compose a new review object with `buyername` property. `Promise.all` returns an array of the mapped `data` which is the new `reviews` state.

```
const getReviews = async () => {
  const { data } = await ReviewsApi.get(`/${itemId}/`);
  
  const reviews = await Promise.all(data.map(getReviewGiverName));

  setReviews(reviews) 
}

const getReviewGiverName = async (review) => {
  const { data } = await api.get(`/${review.buyer}/`);

  return {
    ...review,
    buyername: data[0].first_name + ' ' + data1[0].last_name
  };
}
```